# How to use Skipjack (skip32) in Java to randomize sequential integers from a database

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, jce

Based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704946/why-randomize-your-file-names-for-cloud-storage-cdn), I am using a sequential integer as a record ID in my database. I want to obfuscate the integer IDs using Skip32. I found a [Java implementation](http://www.koders.com/java/fid78BE938EB9E90FF880FD398772DC1E41B578917E.aspx?s=Cipher#L11) but I am uncertain of how to initialize it using the standard JCE APIs. I need to encrypt an integer and decrypt it as necessary. Can anyone show me an example of this?

Comment: can you help me with the implementation you used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you found belongs to the [Cryptix project](http://www.cryptix.org/). You need not just this one file, but you should take the whole package. Take the JCE package, install it as a provider. Then you should be able to use

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("SKIPJACK");
```

But actually, instead of using an unsupported library like Cryptix, using the [BouncyCastle](http://bouncycastle.org/java.html) library (or parts thereof) might be more recommendable. They have lots of documentation, and a [SkipJack-implementation](http://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html), too.

I'm not sure why you would need to use Skipjack instead of any cipher which comes with your JRE, though - just for the smaller block size?

If I understand right, Skip32 is a separate cipher (working on 4-byte blocks), just build by similar principles like Skipjack (which works on 8-byte blocks). I didn't find any specification of it, only some C and Perl source code, so I doubt there will be some Java implementation available. Have a look at [Format-preserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) on Wikipedia, or [Can you create a strong blockcipher with small blocksize, given a strong blockcipher of conventional blocksize?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/504/58) on Cryptography Stack Exchange, which show other ways of building a small-block cipher from a larger one.

Comment: I would love to use something already included in the JRE if possible. Skipjack was just recommended to me. I just need to obfuscate sequential integer IDs from my database and also de-obfuscate them. If you know of an implementation that can do that inside the JRE, I would greatly appreciate an example of it. I would prefer only 6-12 characters in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/9/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-2-Secure-permutations-with-block-ciphers) on secure permutations with block ciphers useful in figuring out how to implement it. Any block cipher with a sufficiently short block size will suffice.